# Upgrade JSF application package without downtime

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm interested can I upgrade JSF application without downtime. For example I can store user sessions in database using specific Apache Shiro configuration. But what about the web pages? Can I upgrade web pages without downtime?

Comment: This is not the responsibility of the webapp. This is the responsibility of the webserver. This question is in the wrong corner.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info!